# Emacs find-tag in class scope

Tags: search, emacs, tags

The project I'm working on has a huge number of source file. When I browse through the source files and search for function definitions, I use find-tag. The problem is that there are lots of different classes' member functions have the same name. Let's say class A's header looks like this:

```
class H {
    ...
    long updateInfo();
    ...
}
```

when I move my cursor onto updateInfo, and use find-tag on updateInfo, it will take me to class A's updateInfo first (if there is one), then I will have to cycle through the list to get to class A's updateInfo() definition. I could, howerver, when doing a tag-search, search for H::updateInfo, and get the result directly. My coworker who uses Eclipse teases me about how lame it is, so I'm wondering if emacs comes with a feature that is able to detect the class name and go to the that class's function definition.

Answer (score 1):

With CEDET, `semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle` should do what you want (it also fades out the highlighted method/declaration in a rather neat fashion).  It's mentioned in a tutorial [here](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html#sec11).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, at the end I think I prefer etags-select-mode better. It's does what I need and very light.